# How to display multiple data in a single row based on ID using mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Based on the First `ID` it has Four records data and based on the second ID it has three records.

Currently in view part it's displaying all the seven records in separate row but i required to display two rows but first row should contain four cords in a single row.

```
[HttpPost]
        [MyExceptionHandler]
        public ActionResult ViewModules(int id)
        {
            Domain_Bind();
            dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
            userType type = new userType();
            List<ViewRoleModules> EmpList = type.GetRoleModulesViews(id);
            string sRptModuleIDs = string.Empty;
            foreach (ViewRoleModules emp in EmpList)
            {
                sRptModuleIDs += emp.ModuleID + ",";
            }
            if (sRptModuleIDs != "")
            {
                sRptModuleIDs = sRptModuleIDs.Remove(sRptModuleIDs.Length - 1, 1);
            }

            List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList;
            List<ViewRoleModules> test = new List<ViewRoleModules>();
            foreach (var rid in sRptModuleIDs.Split(','))
            {
                string RID = rid;
                RoleList = type.GetSiteRoleModulesViews(rid);
                foreach (ViewRoleModules vip in RoleList)
                {
                    test.Add(new ViewRoleModules {
                        RoleName = vip.RoleName
                    });
                }
            }

            return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

in `List<ViewRoleModules> test = new List<ViewRoleModules>();` list we are storing seven records but i need separate data based on `ID`

```
public List<ViewRoleModules> GetSiteRoleModulesViews(string rid)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Admin"].ConnectionString))
            {
                List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList = new List<ViewRoleModules>();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("MEDEIL_SiteRoleModules_SelectOne", conn);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleID", Convert.ToInt32(rid));
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {

                    RoleList.Add(

                        new ViewRoleModules
                        {
                            RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RoleID"]),
                            RoleName = Convert.ToString(dr["RoleName"])

                        }
                    );
                }

                return RoleList;
            }
        }
```

[image: Picture]

in above pic it's is show all records separate row but i required to display two rows but first row should contain four cords in a single row.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#DomainID").change(function () {

                var id = $(this).val();
                $("#example tbody tr").remove();

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',

                    url: '@Url.Action("ViewModules")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: id },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = '';
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $("#findValue").show();
                            var rows = "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + i + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.ModuleName + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.Url + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.RoleName + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>";
                            $('#example tbody').append(rows);
                        });

                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                        alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                        alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });
    </script>
```

[image: Example]

for example above image based on the Leads Id it's displaying multiple role name single row

Comment: Will you please stop tagging your questions with [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/model-view-controller/info)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  okay sir done

Comment: @StephenMuecke any idea? in this question

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: foe example https://forums.asp.net/t/1580379.aspx?Multiple+SQL+rows+merge+into+single+row+if+the+id+is+same+  @monners

Comment: @IvinRaj what is your response data. I think you can solve this issue by using 2 $.each().

Comment: No sir Still my doubt is going on @AbhilashRavindranCK

Comment: @IvinRaj what is your result data inside success method.

Comment: see above my first image that's my output

Comment: i need RoleID 1 - administrator, 2 - superAdmin, 3 - admin

we require output in image 1 Instead of RoleID 1 2 3 we need output as administrator superAdmin admin